# while debugging in visual studio, what does double?[] mean

Tags: c#, arrays

I am debugging c# code in visual studio, and there are variables such as:

```
double?[] x;
string[] y;
```

In locals window I see `x` as `{double?[0]}`  and `y` as `{string[0]}`.
what does that mean?

Comment: It means it's an array of type `double?`, which is a nullable double. The braces `{ }` mean nothing, it's just part of the way VS displays items in the debugger.

Answer (score 9):

- `double?[]` is an array of `double?` objects, which is just C#'s shorthand for `System.Nullable<System.Double>[]`.
- `string[]` is an array of strings, which is the same as `System.String[]`.

**Further Reading**

- [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Types (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx)

Comment: But why does the value y show as {string[0]}.  Is that a string at 0 index within the array?

Comment: As @DaveZych indicated, it's just how the debugger displays it. The `[0]` indicates that it's an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The double keyword signifies a simple type that stores 64-bit floating-point values.

Comment: The question is about `double?[]` so you have only addressed part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark after any type like 
`int?` or 
`double?` shows that this type is nullable.
Square braces show that this is an array.
The number inside the braces represents the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to keep it very simple.

Anything that ends with `[]` means that it is an array of that object type.

`int[]` is an array of `int`,

`string[]` is an array of `string`,

`float?[]` is an array of `float?`,

`MyOwnClass[]` is an array of `MyOwnClass` and so on...

An array is a collection of objects. So if you say `int[] a = new int[5]`, you are creating an array of `int` that can hold 5 `int` values. So if you want to have three `int`s, instead of declaring `int a`, `int b`, `int c`, you just create `int[] myArray = new int[3]`. Just imagine creating all those ints, not for just three elements, but for a thousand elements. It is not practical, so we have arrays.

In C#, there are data types (`int`, `float`, `long` etc) that can hold numeric values, and there are classes that don't have numeric values, but have a collection of more-complex values. Classes are not accessed directly, when you access a class in C# (e.g. `myClass.myValue`), `myClass` is actually just a reference to that class instance (that has `myValue` and all the other values attached to it). In other words, `myClass` object points to an "address" at your computer's RAM. At that "address", your actual data (with `myValue` etc.) is located. But what if `myClass` doesn't point to any address? Then, it's a null pointer, meaning that, the `myClass` points to "the address zero", in other words, `myClass` points to an invalid, non-existant object.

An integer can have any integer value, e.g. 1, 0, -1500, 50000 etc. What if, you want to be able to set an `int` (or any other primitive data type) to null, like the class example? You put a `?` after the type, so instead of `int`, you type `int?`. It is a special "nullable" type, which you can also set to null just like a class.

So regarding your original question:

If we now know that `int` is a simple integer,

`int[]` is a collection of integers,

`int?` is an integer that can also have the special "null" value.

Then `double?[] x` means "a collection of special, nullable `double`s (that is a primitive data type like `int`)". Why? Break it into pieces: you first typed `double`, telling that we are dealing with the data type called `double`, then you've added `?`, meaning that the `double` type that we are dealing with has this special ability to become null, and then you've added `[]`, meaning that we are dealing with a collection of "whatever was before `[]`", in this case, `double?`.